# How to fix ImportError "_psutil_linux" on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, psutil

I need psutil in my code but I get the error "importError _psutil_linux" on Heroku

it's for a status application on the use of the system and what's left of free.

I've already tried:

```
- to force the installation with pip (not work)
- to change the version with the file requirements.txt (not work)
```

requirements.txt :

```
Unidecode==1.0.22
youtube_dl==2018.7.21
chardet==3.0.4
urlextract==0.8.3
feedparser==5.2.1
requests==2.18.4
setuptools==40.2.0
aiohttp==1.0.5
urllib3==1.22
discord.py==0.16.12
psutil==5.4.7
pip==9.0.3
pyparsing==2.2.0
Pillow==5.3.0
beautifulsoup4==4.6.3
httplib2==0.11.3
imgurpython==1.1.7
keyboard==0.13.2
google_api_python_client==1.7.4
pyfiglet==0.7.5
pylast==2.4.0
r6sapi==0.8.0
raven==6.9.0
raven_aiohttp==0.7.0
tabulate==0.8.2
typing==3.6.6
```

my use of psutil :

```
import psutil
CPU = psutil.cpu_percent()
RAM =psutil.virtual_memory().percent
```

(in a discord bot command.)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/cogs/owner.py", line 65, in load
self._load_cog(module)
File "/app/cogs/owner.py", line 946, in _load_cog
mod_obj = importlib.import_module(cogname)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/app/cogs/cyvgeneral.py", line 7, in <module>
import psutil
File "lib/psutil/__init__.py", line 100, in <module>
from . import _pslinux as _psplatform
File "lib/psutil/_pslinux.py", line 26, in <module>
from . import _psutil_linux as cext
ImportError: cannot import name '_psutil_linux'
```

I expect Psutil to load correctly.

thank you in advance.

Comment: it's a runtime error.

Comment: I was able to deploy a minimal test application using `psutil` without doing anything special. How are you trying to import and use it? Please [edit] your question again and show us.

Comment: I edited and added the traceback.

Comment: That code [works just fine for me on Heroku](https://desolate-garden-32536.herokuapp.com/psutil). What do you get when you run `heroku buildpacks` and `heroku stack`? What version of Python are you using, e.g. via `heroku run python --version`?

Comment: heroku buildpacks return  : 'heroku/python'
heroku stack return : 'cedar-14\n
  container\n
  heroku-16\n
* heroku-18'
python --version return : Python 3.6.8

Comment: That's the same as what I have. I tried adding all the rest of your requirements and got some version mismatches locally (between `requests` and `idna`, and between `aiohttp` and `raven_aiohttp`), but that didn't cause import issues with `psutil` locally or on Heroku. There must be something else going on here... can you provide any more code context? I see a directory called `cogs/`; are you using [this](https://bitbucket.org/prometheus/cogs/src/default/)?

Comment: No, I don't use it. The directory called "cogs/" is a "plugin" directory where .py files are stored (for commands.) if you want, I can provide the complete command code.